# Move "Submitted By" from node.tpl to page.tpl

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-7

I'm looking to move "Submitted By" info from node.tpl to page.tpl however when I add the following from node.tpl I get errors.  Im assuming I dont have access to those variables, but would like to know how I can set up a pre-proccess to get it to display as it does in the node.tpl

```
  <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
    <div class="submitted">
      <?php print $submitted; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a preprocess function in the template.php of your theme, as explained here:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40222/how-can-i-print-node-authors-last-login-date-on-page-tpl-php

In your case it would look like this (tested on Drupal 7):

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['author'] = "";
  if (isset($variables['node']) && ($account = user_load($variables['node']->uid))) {
    $variables['author'] = $account->name;
  }
}
```

And then in your page.tpl.php use this:

```
Submitted by: <?php print $author; ?>
```

If you don’t want to touch any of your theme’s files, but you need to output the author’s name in another region as the node content, you could create a view (block display) containing the node author, and assign it to the region.

Answer (score 0):

While normally done in `node.tpl.php`, if the page is a node view page, the $node variable is also available in `page.tpl.php`

You can then use something like:

```
if (isset($node)) {
  // Check if display submitted variable is set for this node type
  if (variable_get('node_submitted_'. $node->type, 0)) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

An alternative approach would be adding the required logic instead to an implementation of

```
hook_preprocess_page
```

Bonus update: You can see the $node variable added to page.tpl.php in core `template_preprocess_page`

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $variables['node'] = $node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `page.tpl.php`:

```
<div class="submitted">
     <?php echo format_date($node->created, 'custom','d.m.Y'); ?><br />
     <?php echo 'by ' . $node->name; ?>
</div>
```